# Route Parameters as Composite Slug

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I am trying to use a composite slug (two route parameters) for a view.

**Scenario**

'John Doe' has written a book titled 'Blue Pill'. I want the slug for every book to look something like this `/books/john-doe-blue-pill`

In Routes, I have:

```
Route::get('/books/{author}-{slug}', 'BookController@show')->name('show_book');
```

In the Listing page, I am pointing to each one like so:

```
<a href="{{ route('show_book', ['author' => str_slug($book->author->name), 'slug' => $book->slug]) }}">
```

**The Problem**

The controller action prints these parameters as: `author = john` and `slug = doe-blue-pill`

**Rejected Options (and why)**

1. I could use a slash `Route::get('/books/{author}/{slug}', ...` but I am trying to keep things as flat as possible and keep the levels to the barest minimum.
2. I could save `john-doe-blue-pill` to the db as the slug for the book, but this would get messy if the author later decides to change their name (e.g a female author after marriage).

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are using in slag dash and using dash for dividing params - how laravel will knows what is slug or what is divider? use underscore between two slugs or underscore in slugs and dash as divider

Comment: Hi @omadonex, Yes I understand what's happening, I just asked to see if there's a way around it. I want to keep it all hyphens.

Comment: You could have a single {slug} then explode the author/title in the controller.

Comment: How would you envision this works? What if the author had 1 name, or three names? and the book was 6 words? How would you handle this? seems like too much work, separate it out into /books/{author}/{slug} imo.

Comment: Hi @jfadich, I don't quite understand what you mean. How would I know where the artist name ends?

Comment: Hi @Ohgodwhy, I just thought Laravel was smart enough to know where parameters were located regardless of separators. Is there someway I can encode those parameters so Laravel doesn't see the hyphens in them?

Comment: No, there isn't really anyway for Laravel to know where the slug should be separated (unless the author part of the slug was always going to be the same amount of words). With passing the whole thing to the controller you would need to explode slug and query the database for each piece until you found a match. If you're set on not using `/` then it wouldn't be that much of an issue to store the author in the slug, assuming that you have an author relationship. If their name does get changed you could simply to spin through the books and change the slug accordingly. Use a queue job if needs be.